# Getting id of an item instead of value, django forms

Tags: python, django

I have created a form and I wanted to create a field that is for display only, after adding that line, the form started returning id instead of the value.

```
class AmendLoan(ModelForm):
  borrower = forms.CharField(disabled=True)

  class Meta:
      model = BikeInstance

      fields = (
          'borrower',
          'due_back',
          'status'
     )
```

Any ideas, how to display value of borrower, instead of id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
    super(AmendLoan, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['borrower'].disabled = True
```

you can disable the field this way

Comment: it wont let me save the new data in the form, because of this. Any idea why?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to access the value of borrower in your html file, you can write :

```
{{ AmendLoan.borrower }}
```

Comment: still shows id, it shows the value if I remove `borrower = forms.CharField(disabled=True)`, but I want that field to be read only

Comment: You can comment it out

Comment: I know, but that doesn't change the thing, that I need that field to be read only